# Do we must show link to Google Terms when using Mapkit?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am using Mapkit for Google Maps. According to their terms at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html:

> 9.3 End User Terms and Privacy Policy. If you develop a Maps API Implementation for use by other users, you must:
>
> (a) display to the users of your Maps API Implementation the link to Google's Terms of Use as presented through the Service or described in the Maps API Documentation;

Where can I show link to Google's ToU? I do not have an About screen in my app.
Is it must to show one? I see apps on iTunes who do not have an About screen and nobody shows the link on the main map screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This section means if you make your own API, like an add-on, or something that alters the MapKit, you need to link to their terms.

If you are just using the MapKit in your app, then no, there's no need to do anything extra.